# how to extract gzipped file in a different directory

Tags: cmd, gzip

I am currently using this command to do a restore in mysql of a gzipped file.

```
C:\...directory of gzip.exe >gunzip -c filename.gz | mysql -u.. -p.. -P.. -h dbname
```

I would like to extract files that are located in a directory that is different from the one in which gzip.exe is located.
How should i modify the instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the directory containing the .gz file and either 1) specify the path to gunzip.exe or 2) add the directory containing gunzip.exe to your PATH variable.

```
"C:\path\to\gunzip.exe" -c filename.gz | mysql -u.. -p.. -P.. -h dbname
```